# Using a earlier made Column

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I'm making a stored procedure where I have declared a column with the AS "NameofColumn" method. Now I want to use that value again later in the stored procedure. Is there anyway to do this?

```
      CASE 
     WHEN ((select top 1 stuksweergeven from componenten where componentid = componentlink.componentid) = 1) and  ((select AmountKG from componenten where componentid = componentlink.componentid) <> 0) THEN 
        Amount * (select AmountKG from componenten where componentid = componentlink.componentid)
     ELSE 
        Amount 
  END AS Amount
```

Now later I want to do the following

```
Amount * 10 AS TotalAmount
```

Comment: You need to use a subquery or CTE, if you want to re-use a column alias defined in a `SELECT`.

Answer (score 0):

Use subquery where you count the "Amount" and then make select to from that subquery . Something like that:

```
select Amount * 10 AS TotalAmount from ( SELECT CASE 
         WHEN ((select top 1 stuksweergeven from componenten where componentid = componentlink.componentid) = 1) and  ((select AmountKG from componenten where componentid = componentlink.componentid) <> 0) THEN 
            Amount * (select AmountKG from componenten where componentid = componentlink.componentid)
         ELSE 
            Amount 
      END AS Amount FROM yourtable )e
```